# iFrame buttons not working

Tags: html, css, button, iframe

I have emails forms written in PHP. My team members on my website all have their own email addresses. Instead of creating each team members a web page for their email contact form, I did iFrames with buttons that redirect to each form that contacts that team member. 
. So I have three iFrames each with 2 buttons. I will add more buttons to some of the iFrames. My current code does not work. The buttons are not working.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
}

.embed-responsive-16by9::before {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

.col-md-4 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-4 {
        max-width: 33.33333%;
        flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    }
}
```

```html
accept
You can use below code for 3 columns

HTML:

<body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://google.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T" />
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U" />
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://www.phpform.org/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T" />
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://youtube.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U" />
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://mail.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T" />
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://php.net/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U" />
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I want to be able to click a button an have another page open inside the iFrame. I want to dedicate each button to this function. Please help.

@Gerfried  That does not work. This is my original code that works. I have a post on S.O-where i asked how to make columns for my iFrames. Once i used the CSS script towards my coding, my iFrames buttons will not work. This is my original code before the CSS columns script.  The code below have working buttons but i want that code in three columns. I tried a few things with no success.

```html
<p><input type="button" onclick="one.location.href='https://klientboost.com/';document.getElementById('one').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="one.location.href='https://klientboost.com/#getProposal';document.getElementById('one').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="one" id="one" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='https://klientboost.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='https://klientboost.com/#getProposal';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="two" id="two" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="three.location.href='https://klientboost.com/';document.getElementById('three').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="three.location.href='https://klientboost.com/#getProposal';document.getElementById('three').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="three" id="three" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('one').src='https://klientboost.com/#getProposal'" value="T">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="one" id="one" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('two').src='https://klientboost.com/#getProposal'" value="T">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="two" id="two" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('three').src='https://klientboost.com/#getProposal'" value="T">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="three" id="three" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>
```

1. The iFrame's location is src, not href:

   onclick="document.getElementById('two').src='https://google.com/'"
2. Give an id to the iframe

   <iframe id="two" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
3. Your Sample URLs (e.g. Google) will not load in an iFrame, because they have set `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` in their headers.

Comment: See the new sample in my answer. You forgot the apostrophes around the url strings.

Comment: I do not know the term "apostrophes" can you give me an example of the line of code please

Comment: you might want to look into a dictionary.

Comment: great job buddy- You have the ability to type in  8 words 40 character, but unable to give and example to answer the question. Keep up the good work buddy. Poor examples of forum Etiquette  are  paired with social interactions. But a good stereotypical example of information technology professionals.